# how to write junits for handleEvent() in JAVA

Tags: java, events, junit, mocking, aem

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(value = EventHandler.class)
@Property(name = EventConstants.EVENT_TOPIC, value = "org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource/*")
public class SimpleResourceListener implements EventHandler {

    //private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleResourceListener.class);

    public void  handleEvent(final Event event) {
        LOGGER.debug("Resource event: {} at: {}", event.getTopic(), event.getProperty(SlingConstants.PROPERTY_PATH));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try to use mock framework to achive it? Mockito, Powermock, or Spock

Comment: I haven't given a try, since I am new to JUNITs and I am learning these days how to write those. May be an example would help me in this case.

Comment: You can find an example in ACS https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/bundle/src/test/java/com/adobe/acs/commons/replication/status/impl/JcrPackageReplicationStatusEventHandlerTest.java